# Record analytic rank for an elliptic curve?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

What is the current record (and reference) for the highest analytic rank of an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$?

The highest algebraic rank is the Elkies curve with rank at least 28, but I cannot determine whether its analytic rank has been computed with any certainty.

Comment: Only rank $3$ after Gross--Zagier.  Anything higher would have nice consequences for lower bounds for class numbers (improving the power of log in the effective bound).

Comment: The problem is to *prove* that a higher derivative of the $L$-function, evaluated at 1, indeed vanishes, if it appears to do so numerically. This can be done for the value itself and the first derivative, but so far not for higher ones.

Comment: @MichaelStoll Ah, I hadn't realized that one could prove that the first derivative vanishes, but not the second. (I had thought one couldn't even prove the first derivative vanished). Is there an intuitive description of the block? Stated differently, I'd thought that our lack of ability to understand Sha would have made many generic approaches fail.

Comment: As stated, the record is unbounded, if you allow (number) fields other than Q...

Comment: @literature-searcher ah yes, you're right. Thank you. I've corrected that now.

Comment: @davidlowryduda One reason the Gross-Zagier formula is so central (pun not intended) is that it makes it possible to prove that the first derivative vanishes when it does.

Comment: @literature-searcher Do you have a reference for that? Unlike algebraic rank, it is not clear to me how passing to a curve over a nunber field would make analytic rank easier to bound.

Comment: @Wojowu I guess a way to proceed is to prove that there are infinitely many quadratics twists with vanishing central value. Taking the base change of the elliptic curve to the (abelian) extension generated by these quadratic fields, you get unbounded analytic ranks (the base changed $L$-function factors as the products of the twists by the Dirichlet characters, like the Dedekind zeta function factors as a product of Artin $L$-functions).

Comment: Indeed, just take arbitrarily many quadratic twists of $E/{\bf Q}$ with odd parity, and consider over the relevant multiquadratic field.